# Problema com um código SVG no HTML

Tags: html, css, svg

Eu adicionei um código svg de uma vector image 3D no meu código html para animar com css. O problema é que o código svg é enorme (3k linhas de código ou mais) no HTML e foi a única maneira que encontrei para animar os elementos do svg separadamente por que as layers do arquivo são separadas por ID'S. existiria alguma maneira de esconder o código do svg do HTML ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Esse é o StackOverflow **em português**, traduza sua pergunta ou a faça no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Esconder o código SVG do HTML? Cria um arquivo `.svg` e "importa" no HTML, estaria "escondido". É isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua pergunta tem uma pontas soltas. Mas vou te dar algumas dicas que podem te ajudar.

Primeiro é preciso deixar claro que vc pode por exemplo ter um SVG onde vc vai animar os seus vetores usando propriedades do CSS como transform, opacite, etc, tudo pelo CSS, mas dentro do próprio SVG. Ou vc pode animar tudo diretamente com o métodos de animação do SVG usado as tag nativas dele como `<animate>`, `<set>` e `<animateMotion>` por exemplo.

Independente do método, como inclusive o @GuilhermeCostamilam comentou vc pode posteriormente chamar a imagem do SVG no HTML, usando a tag `<img>` mesmo, ex: `<img src="meu-svg.svg" alt="">`

Exemplo de SVG com os métodos nativos (*aqui tem um guia completo de como animar SVGs nativamente* https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 160 160" width="160" height="160">

  <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="50" />
  <g transform=" matrix(0.866, -0.5, 0.25, 0.433, 80, 80)">
    <path d="M 0,70 A 65,70 0 0,0 65,0 5,5 0 0,1 75,0 75,70 0 0,1 0,70Z" fill="#F00">
      <animateTransform 
      attributeName="transform" 
      type="rotate" 
      from="360 0 0" 
      to="0 0 0" 
      dur="1s" 
      repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>
  </g>
  <path d="M 50,0 A 50,50 0 0,0 -50,0Z" transform="matrix(0.866, -0.5, 0.5, 0.866, 80, 80)" />

</svg>
```

---

Exemplo usando CSS dentro do próprio SVG.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 160 160" width="160" height="160">
  <defs>
    <style>
      #triangle {
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 65%;
                transform-origin: 50% 65%;
      }
      #triangle polygon {
        stroke-dasharray: 17;
        -webkit-animation: dash 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0.04, 0.63, 0.95) infinite;
                animation: dash 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0.04, 0.63, 0.95) infinite;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes dash {
        to {
          stroke-dashoffset: 136;
        }
      }
      @keyframes dash {
        to {
          stroke-dashoffset: 136;
        }
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
        100% {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                  transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
      @keyframes rotate {
        100% {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                  transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
    </style>
  </defs>

  <g id="triangle" width="160px" height="160px" >
    <polygon fill="#EFEFEF" stroke="#333333" stroke-width="1" points="16,0 32,32 0,32"></polygon>
  </g>

</svg>
```

---

> O ponto aqui é que independente da técnica de animação vc consegue indexar seu SVG no HTML como uma imagem qualquer `<img src="meu-svg.svg" alt="">` . Então se vc quer animar com CSS vc não precisa do HTML para isso.

***Aqui tem um link de um SVG Animado com CSS interno e importado como imagem em um HTML:*** https://hugocsl.github.io/svg/stof.html

Além disso, vc tb pode animar o seu SVG em algum software como o **Svgator** por exemplo e depois exportar a animação. (https://www.svgator.com/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta detalhada! Desde já peço desculpas pela pergunta sem pé nem cabeça KKKK. Basicamente o que eu tava procurando seria como animar as svgs nativamente. Como eu uso o illustrator pra criar as imagens cada layer que eu crio é separada no código SVG por ID's, dando a liberdade de com o css, selecionar essas ids e animar elas separadamente mas como consequência eu teria que colocar o código do SVG no HTML (3mil e algumas poucas linhas KKKK).

Comment: @joãopaulosantan tranquilo deu para entender. Vc pode soldar alguns elementos para tentar diminuir a quantidade de layers. E depois que estiver tudo animado vc pode usar algum minificador da svg tipo o svgomg. Boa sorte ai qq duvida eh só perguntar